# Should a GUI for writing a blog articles submit data into a database or create a file for each article?

Tags: blogs

I'm creating a form for writing articles which will then be automatically published on my website. Should these articles be saved as data in a database, or should the form create a file for each article? I'm sure there are advantages/disadvantages for each, but they are eluding me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - Use a Database.

1) If you are using a framework such as PHP's Laravel or Ruby on Rails etc, these framework are designed to talk to databases and use ORM or Object Relational Mapping to make this process as simple as possible.

2) Assuming your site has the traditional blog characteristics such as: Authors, Editors, Admins, Meta Tags, Search Fields, Related Articles etc. This is going to require additional data tables such as a users table, categories, tags, permissions and so on. You will then need to tie all of these elements together to show the author of a post, all posts by a certain author, whether someone can edit a post...the list goes on. This is what databases are designed to do: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)

3) Security. A database allows you to create different users with different permissions to perform activities such as creating records, deleting etc. You can also store encrypted data easily like passwords or payment details.

4) Performance. SQL queries, indexed tables etc is going to result in better performance on your site.

5) Maintenance. In terms of maintenance of your project, most programmers are going to expect and be comfortable with a database driven website. In terms of data maintenance, it's a lot easier to retrieve data, backup, restore, archive etc using SQL then files on a file system.

There are many more benefits to using a database but hopefully the above is enough to point you in the right direction. I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you brad. There are some benefits of Databases there I had not thought about, like indexing for searching and data maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

If your case not very very special, use database. 
Could you tell me about one advantage of using file? Just think about managing(edit, delete,...) the article in file, you would have to rewrite a basic database.

Comment: I thought maybe creating new files for each article might provide benefit in that I wouldn't have to create or maintain a database, and changing anything in future articles might be easier because I wouldn't have to concern myself with how the changes would affect everything else in the DB. Anyway, I think I'm going to go with a DB. Thanks!